# I'm facing the problem when run the apps, the apk file didn't install in my phone

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

What going wrong with my code? Is it any problem in mymanifest file? Please suggest any way to make it show out the apk in my phone. :(

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.edward.eventmanagementsystem">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ems"
        android:label="@string/title_application"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".StartUpPage.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_application">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenuPage.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ManageEvent.ManageEventMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manage_event_menu" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ManageEvent.CreateEvent"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_event" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ManageEvent.ListOfEvent"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_of_event" />

        <activity android:name=".StartUpPage.Register" />

        <activity android:name=".StartUpPage.LoginPage"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also that, i found that my code mostly is yellow color when show out in the android studio. Is that any probelm or coding way is wrong?

LogFile

[Log File Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEro4.png)

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: `What going wrong with my code` what code? `my code mostly is yellow color` what code? `Is that any probelm or coding` what code?

Comment: Have you got any error messages?

Comment: I have update my post with the logcatphoto below the manifest file

Comment: Try to clean and build your project

Answer (score 0):

What error you are getting while installing the app?

Also, your device first ask you that you want to install this app or not, Only  when you  provide permission after the app will be installed.

Also, check in your device's settings if there's some permission which is not letting the app install.

If you can't get anything the simplest way to install app to your phone is:
1) Build an apk from android studio transfer it to your device.
2) install the apk from your storage.

It worked for me many times.